# How to translate a phrase in Magento 2.1 checkout?

Tags: magento2, localisation

In checkout, under the "Summary" area, I've been able to translate "2 items in cart" using this entry in the .CSV file:

`%1 items in cart, %1 artículos en tu carrito, module, Magento_Checkout`

This works for 2,3,4... items in cart. However I haven't been able to translate "**1** item in cart".

I've tried these entries:

`%s item in cart, %1 artículo en tu carrito, module, Magento_Checkout`

`1 item in cart, 1 artículo en tu carrito, module, Magento_Checkout`

None of them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a grep for the class that the text is in `.items-in-cart` and found the template that is being used **vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/cart-items.html**. This is a [knockout js](http://knockoutjs.com/) template, and they have their own logic to how they work and how they are called. But the piece of code that you are looking for is:

```
<div class="title" data-role="title">
    <strong role="heading"><span data-bind="text: getItemsQty()"></span>
        <!-- ko if: getItemsQty() == 1 -->
        <!-- ko i18n: 'Item in Cart' --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: getItemsQty() > 1 -->
        <!-- ko i18n: 'Items in Cart' --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </strong>
</div>
```

You can see from the code that they are using knockout to set the value in a `<span>` tag and sets the text after wrapped in a `ko i18n:` translation tag. So in theory you should be able to use the text `"Item in Cart"` in the translation file and it will translate for you.

Comment: Not a chance for this. I've added custom translate for header minicart but i18n text was not translated.
**Go to Checkout**, Ga naar de checkout

Comment: I'm not sure i'm understanding you correctly, but what file are you placing the translation in? Are you able to do any other translation in that file, just not the "Go to Checkout"? Make sure that the translation file is working first and then we can trouble shoot what might be going wrong.

Comment: Yes my translation file works when it comes to translate other strings. Texts `Go to Checkout` and `View and edit cart` from header minicart is not translated.

Answer (score 1):

"1 item in cart" is display form Below file.
**vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/cart-items.html**

```
<div class="title" data-role="title">
<strong role="heading"><span data-bind="text: getItemsQty()"></span>
    <!-- ko if: getItemsQty() == 1 -->
    <!-- ko i18n: 'Item in Cart' --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: getItemsQty() > 1 -->
    <!-- ko i18n: 'Items in Cart' --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</strong>
```

For translation text **Item in Cart** You need to create module follow below step.

**Step-1** create foldar  **app/i18n/OnTap/en_GB/**

**step-2**  create  composer.json  file

### **app/i18n/OnTap/en_GB/composer.json**

```
{
  "name": "ontap/language-en_gb",
  "description": "English (GB) language",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "require": {
    "magento/framework": "100.1.*"
  },
  "type": "magento2-language",
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Step-3** create app/i18n/OnTap/en_GB/language.xml

`<?xml version="1.0"?> "urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd">
    <code>en_GB</code>
    <vendor>OnTap</vendor>
    <package>en_GB</package>
</language>`

**step-4** create app/i18n/OnTap/en_GB/registration.php

`<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
    'ontap_en_gb',
    __DIR__
);`

**step-5** create csv file app/i18n/OnTap/en_GB/en_GB.csv add below text

`Item in Cart,Item in Basket`

**remove static data from pub/static/**

rm -rf pub/static/frontend

**remove cache**

rm -rf var/cache/ var/generation/ var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/

**genrate static data**

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Now Item in Cart is display with **Item in Basket**

Comment: text is inside web/ foldar path so that's why you need to create module.
web/template/summary/cart-items.html

Using this module You can traslate nay web/template text like
My Cart (1 item),My Basket (1 item)
My Cart (%1 items),My Basket (%1 items)